# Cumulative effects of Runed Skills

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

The Gloom rune of the demon hunter's Shadow Power skill is as follows:

[image]

Is the 35% reduction in incoming damage *in addition* to the 15% damage done as Life, or *instead* of it?

I sometimes have difficulty determining this for other runes. For example, the witch doctor's Rabid Dogs rune indicates "Your Zombie Dogs *gain* an infectious bite..." and "Swallow your Soul" indicates "Gain X mana...". In these cases, the effect specifically indicates that it is in *addition* ("gain") to the base skill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what "damage done as Life" means.  When Shadow Power is active, 15% of the damage *you deal to others* is returned to you as life.  Therefore, there is no overlap between the base effect and the rune effect; you gain life from damage dealt while also reducing the damage you receive from mobs.

In case this wasn't the misunderstanding, then yes you do get both effects.  A rune effect only replaces the base effect if there is wording to that nature, for instance, the [Companion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/companion) rune effects all say "instead of a raven."

Comment: I did not misunderstand, so the second part of your answer is what I was looking for. Thanks.